# jquery sum and subtract prices from checkbox with initial price with category

Tags: jquery

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
i want if check "pilih semua" then total use price "pilih semua"
but if not check "pilih semua " then price +=  item
please help me

this sample
i want if check all then price 1000 not 1900
please help me, please help me, please help me, please help me, please help me, please help me, please help me, please help me, please help me

```js
                                                $(document).ready(function() {
                                  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input.subOption1'),
                                    checkall = document.getElementById('option1');

                                  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {

                                    checkboxes[i].onclick = function() {
                                      var checkedCount = document.querySelectorAll('input.subOption1:checked').length;

                                      checkall.checked = checkedCount > 0;
                                      checkall.indeterminate = checkedCount > 0 && checkedCount < checkboxes.length;

                                    }
                                  }


                                  checkall.onclick = function() {
                                    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                                      checkboxes[i].checked = this.checked;
                  
                                    }

                                  }


                                  $('input:checkbox').change(function() {

                                    var total = 0;
                                    var totalkat = 0;

                                    $("input[name='id_kat_lab[]']:checked").each(function() { // iterate through each checked element.
                                      totalkat += isNaN(parseInt($(this).data('harga'))) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).data('harga'));
                                    });

                                    $("input[name='id_item[]']:checked").each(function() { // iterate through each checked element.
                                      total += isNaN(parseInt($(this).data('harga'))) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).data('harga'));
                                    });


                                    $("#totallab").val(totalkat + total);


                                  });
                                });
```

```css
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76002314/edit#
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="row gutters">
                            <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-12 tesrow">
                                
                                <div class="card tes">
                                   
                                    <div class="card-body tes-body" id="kompatibility">
                                       

                                        <ul class="list-group m-0 komp">
                                            <li class="liutama" >
                                               Categori 1
                                            </li>

                                             <li class="komp list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                                <input id="option1" name="id_kat_lab[]" type="checkbox" value="1" data-harga="1000" aria-label="...">


                                               All <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill"> 
                                                    Rp .1000
                                      </span>
                                            </li>
                                            
                                            <li class="komp list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center ">
                                                <input class="subOption1" type="checkbox" name="id_item[]" value="1" aria-label="..." data-harga="200" >
                                                chicken <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">Rp. 200
                                                
                                            </span>
                                            </li>

                                            <li class="komp list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center ">
                                                <input class="subOption1" type="checkbox" name="id_item[]" value="2" aria-label="..." data-harga="400" >
                                                chicken 2 <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">Rp. 400
                                                
                                            </span>
                                            </li>

                                            <li class="komp list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center ">
                                                <input class="subOption1" type="checkbox" name="id_item[]" value="3" aria-label="..." data-harga="300" >
                                                chicken 3 <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">Rp. 300
                                                
                                            </span>
                                            </li>

                                           
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            

                         <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-12 ">
                    <div class="input-group">
                         <span class="input-group-text">
                                 Total
                            </span>
                           <input type="number" class="form-control" class="totallab" id="totallab">
                           
                        </div>

                  
                </div>
```

Comment: Not clear on what you are asking can you explain a bit more

Comment: Please provide minimal working example

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zacka321/pu0ej748/10/   i want if check all then price 1000 not 1900

Answer (score 0):

Just comment `checkAll.onclick` section to get a total = `1000`.

```js
...
checkall.onclick = function() {
//for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
//  checkboxes[i].checked = this.checked;
//  dikurang += parseInt(<?php echo $ro['hargas'];?>);
//}
}
...
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input.subOption1'),
      checkall = document.getElementById('option1');



    var dikurang = 0;
    // var totalharga = $("#harga_kelompok<?php echo $no; ?>").val();

    // var numberNotChecked = $('input:checkbox:not(":checked")').length;

    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {

      checkboxes[i].onclick = function() {
        var checkedCount = document.querySelectorAll('input.subOption<?php echo $no; ?>:checked').length;

        checkall.checked = checkedCount > 0;
        checkall.indeterminate = checkedCount > 0 && checkedCount < checkboxes.length;

      }
    }


    checkall.onclick = function() {
      //for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      //  checkboxes[i].checked = this.checked;
        // dikurang += parseInt(<?php echo $ro['hargas'];?>);
      //}

    }

    // $('#checkbox_id').is(":checked"); 

    // var a= $('#option<?php echo $no; ?>').is(':checked');

    $('input:checkbox').change(function() {

      var total = 0;
      var totalkat = 0;

      $("input[name='id_kat_lab[]']:checked").each(function() { // iterate through each checked element.
        totalkat += isNaN(parseInt($(this).data('harga'))) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).data('harga'));
      });

      $("input[name='id_item[]']:checked").each(function() { // iterate through each checked element.
        total += isNaN(parseInt($(this).data('harga'))) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).data('harga'));
      });


      $("#totallab").val(totalkat + total);


    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row gutters">
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-12 tesrow">

        <div class="card tes">

            <div class="card-body tes-body" id="kompatibility">


                <ul class="list-group m-0 komp">
                    <li class="liutama">
                        Categori 1
                    </li>

                    <li class="komp list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        <input id="option1" name="id_kat_lab[]" type="checkbox" value="1" data-harga="1000" aria-label="..."> All <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill"> 
                                                    Rp .1000
                                      </span>
                    </li>

                    <li class="komp list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center ">
                        <input class="subOption1" type="checkbox" name="id_item[]" value="1" aria-label="..." data-harga="200"> chicken <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">Rp. 200
                                                
                                            </span>
                    </li>

                    <li class="komp list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center ">
                        <input class="subOption1" type="checkbox" name="id_item[]" value="2" aria-label="..." data-harga="400"> chicken 2 <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">Rp. 400
                                                
                                            </span>
                    </li>

                    <li class="komp list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center ">
                        <input class="subOption1" type="checkbox" name="id_item[]" value="3" aria-label="..." data-harga="300"> chicken 3 <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">Rp. 300
                                                
                                            </span>
                    </li>


                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-12 ">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-text">
                                 Total
                            </span>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" class="totallab" id="totallab">

        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simplified your `JS`.

**Notice:** Your sum of options is not equal to the `Check All`. So if you want the total to be sum of options just replace every `showTotal();` with `showTotal(priceList);`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let checkall = document.getElementById('option1'), $checkboxes = $('input.subOption1'), priceList = [], $total = $("#totallab");
  $(document).on('change', 'input.subOption1', function(ev){
      if(ev.currentTarget.checked)
        priceList.push(+ev.currentTarget.dataset.harga || 0);
      else
        calculate();
      let filtered = $checkboxes.not(':checked').length;
      showTotal(priceList);
      checkall.checked = !filtered;
      checkall.indeterminate = filtered % $checkboxes.length;
      if(filtered == 0)
        showTotal();
  });
  $(document).on('change', '#option1', function(ev){
      $checkboxes.prop('checked', ev.currentTarget.checked);
      showTotal();
  });
  
  function showTotal(prices){
        if(prices == undefined)
          prices = [checkall.checked? +checkall.dataset.harga || 0 : 0];
        $total.val(prices.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0));
  }
  
  function calculate(prices){
    priceList = [];
    $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function(i, el){
      priceList.push(+el.dataset.harga || 0);
    });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row gutters">
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-12 tesrow">

    <div class="card tes">

      <div class="card-body tes-body" id="kompatibility">


        <ul class="list-group m-0 komp">
          <li class="liutama">
            Categori 1
          </li>

          <li class="komp list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <input id="option1" name="id_kat_lab[]" type="checkbox" value="1" data-harga="1000" aria-label="..."> All <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill"> 
                                                    Rp .1000
                                      </span>
          </li>

          <li class="komp list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center ">
            <input class="subOption1" type="checkbox" name="id_item[]" value="1" aria-label="..." data-harga="200"> chicken <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">Rp. 200
                                                
                                            </span>
          </li>

          <li class="komp list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center ">
            <input class="subOption1" type="checkbox" name="id_item[]" value="2" aria-label="..." data-harga="400"> chicken 2 <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">Rp. 400
                                                
                                            </span>
          </li>

          <li class="komp list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center ">
            <input class="subOption1" type="checkbox" name="id_item[]" value="3" aria-label="..." data-harga="300"> chicken 3 <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">Rp. 300
                                                
                                            </span>
          </li>


        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-12 ">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-text">
                                 Total
                            </span>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" class="totallab" id="totallab">

    </div>


  </div>
```

Comment: but if you uncheck All and checked and uncheck all next checked chicken, total be wrong

Comment: @AhmadZakaria The number off select all is 1000 and number of sum of other options is 900 as you wanted I put the check all number in the box but explained how to change this behavior

Comment: @AhmadZakaria Please accept and vote up if it was helpful